# Checkbox is showing too big in chrome Asp.net MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Why size of check-box not showing same as Firefox, in chrome it seems to be large? here is example of my question [enter link description here](https://www.flyttom.no/flytteskjema)

```
 <label class="chboxs">
 @Html.CheckBox("chboxFlytng", false, new { @class = "chbox" })
 <span style="margin-top: 4px; padding-left: 5px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;">Flytting</span></label>
```

Comment: Can you post the screen shot for this?

Comment: https://www.flyttom.no/flytteskjema

Comment: The reason is simple. You have a class input#chboxFlytng that is being applied to checkbox. This class has `height: 27px`. Remove height from this class and you will be ok.

Comment: Also remove width attribute from the above class.

Comment: if I remove width:67.4%; then suddenly effect on textbox which is also on the page, and when I remove height:27px; then effect on radio button, there size is also decrease..

Comment: Remove the height as I suggested and also remove margin-top:4px for the text that you have. It  will be ok then.

Answer (score 1):

This rule is causing the problem:

```
.col_form input {
    width: 67.4%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    float: left;
}
```

It's setting `width: 67.4%` on all inputs in your `.col_form` elements.

Comment: if I remove width:67.4%; then suddenly effect on textbox which is also on the page, and when I remove height:27px; then effect on radio button, there size is also decrease

Comment: You can qualify the selector to exclude checkboxes: `.col_form input:not([type="checkbox"]) {}`.  Or qualify it for each input you want it to affect: `.col_form input[type="text"], .col_form input[type="password"], ... {}`.